# DICOM - Implicit VR Dictionary

Tags: dicom

When reading Implicit Transfer Syntax:

Which VR should the VR Dictionary return, when there are multiple allowed in DICOM part 11? Like in the case of:

(0028,1101) Red Palette Color Lookup Table Descriptor - allowed vrs: US or SS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition from the DICOM Data Structures and Encoding

Data Elements (0028,1101), (0028,1102),(0028,1103) Red, Green, Blue Palette Lookup
Table Descriptor have the Value Representation SS or US (depending on rules specified
in the IOD in PS 3.3), and shall be encoded in Big Endian. The first and third values are
always interpreted as unsigned, regardless of the Value Representation.

Comment: I do not believe those should be read as Big Endian, but Little Endian instead.

Answer (score 3):

Palette Color Lookup Table Descriptor (0028, 1101-1104) Attributes are multi-valued and the first and third values are always interpreted as unsigned. The second value should be interpreted according to Pixel Representation (0028, 0103). In case of Explicit VR Transfer Syntax, value representation (US or SS) should be consistent with Pixel Representation (0028, 0103).